# Is there a simple way to get the KSM address associated with a generic address using polkadot-js library?

Tags: multiaddress

I'm trying to get the associated KSM address for a generic address. I was wondering if there was a simple way to do this using polkadot-js library

Answer (score 2):

```javascript
const { encodeAddress } = polkadotUtilCrypto;
let kusama_prefix = 2;
let kusama_address = encodeAddress(generic_address, kusama_prefix);
```

For example:

```javascript
polkadotUtilCrypto.encodeAddress("5DksjtJER6oLDWkWKCWcL3f1swPWeNNFsS9zHxa2rPa7LsH9", 2)

> "EGVQCe73TpFyAZx5uKfE1222XfkT3BSKozjgcqzLBnc5eYo"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not in Polkadot{.js} API, however they are simple to use:

- https://polkadot.subscan.io/tools/ss58_transform
- https://polkadot-address-convertor.netlify.app